# Checkbox control not showing up both in the designer and also while debugging

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, .net-core

I'm writing a .NET Core 3.1 WinForms application but I've an issue with checkboxes. They simply don't appear on my form.

I tried to use both Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.5.2 and Visual Studio 2019 Preview Version 16.7.0 Preview 1.0. I activated the option `Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps` (this option seems to be missing on the non-preview VS) but even with that the checkbox control is missing from the designer.

So instead I just manually added my checkboxes in the `MyForm.Designer.cs` file

```cs
// 
// checkboxRotate
// 
this.checkboxRotate.Visible = true;
this.checkboxRotate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 40);
this.checkboxRotate.Name = "checkboxRotate";
this.checkboxRotate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 24);
this.checkboxRotate.TabIndex = 0;
// 
// checkboxFlip
// 
this.checkboxFlip.Visible = true;
this.checkboxFlip.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(370, 40);
this.checkboxFlip.Name = "checkboxFlip";
this.checkboxFlip.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 24);
this.checkboxFlip.TabIndex = 0;
```

I set the locations based on other controls, these checkboxes should be at 40 on the vertical axis and 370 and 400 seem good to me on the horizontal axis.

However when I debug they still don't appear on my form.
I tried to convert the application to .NET 5 (Preview 4 in installed on my machine) but nothing changed.

So how can I get the checkbox control to work? Can I get it in the designer in some way?

All the screenshots on the web are showing the checkbox control in the designer even [this one from 5 days ago](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/). They say the new designer is available in VS 2019 16.7 Preview 1 if the `Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps` option is checked which is exactly what I did.
So why don't I have this control?

Thanks

Comment: I would guess that a fundamental control as a checkbox should just work. Can you create a new project and test there whether it works as expected?

Comment: IIRC, there are some known issues with winforms designer in .net core

Comment: @CodeCaster same with a brand new project

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it's weird they published a new post 5 days ago saying the new designer is available and we can clearly see the checkbox on the screenshot. 
It's been several months I'm facing this issue I don't know how to solve it, I really need this control now

Comment: Do you use Windows 10?

Comment: @preciousbetine Yes Windows 10 up to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticket in the Microsoft Developer Community but it seems someone posted a [similar bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1041288/core-31-winforms-button-missing-from-toolbos.html) few days ago.

The solution that worked for me to fix the designer was to `right click in the Toolbox` then `Choose items` and finally click on the `Reset` button at the lower right corner.

If this workaround doesn't work for you, [another way](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1045118/view.html) is to

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete the following file :`C:\Users{your user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_{***}\privateregistry.bin`
3. Restart Visual Studio

If this doesn't work, try deleting all those files

```
privateregistry.bin
privateregistry.bin.LOG1
privateregistry.bin.LOG2
toolbox.tbd
toolboxIndex.tbd
toolboxIndex_reset.tbd
toolbox_reset.tbd
ToolboxItemDiscoveryCache.7036b125-fa82-3aba-acb8-bdbc97782a06.dat<br>
```

*Note: Note: you may also need to reset your UI customization(theme, position of windows, code styles, etc) after you deleted these files and restarted VS*

As for why my checkboxes weren't showing up after manually adding the code in the `MyForm.Designer.cs` file this is because I've a GroupBox and I simply forgot to add the controls to it

```cs
this.MyGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.checkboxRotate);
this.MyGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.checkboxFlip);
```

If you don't have any GroupBox the control must be added to the form directly

```cs
this.Controls.Add(this.checkboxRotate);
this.Controls.Add(this.checkboxFlip);
```